# How to change v-model value only for the clicked element in an iterator component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have this iterator that displays several components:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRyGmq

The problem is, when I click the menu button on one of them, the value of `menu` v-model changes to `true` for all of them.

Comment: You need to set `v-model` to some property of each `item`. Something like this (but probably not-I don't know much about Vuetify):https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/GQPpMe

Comment: @Bert yeah, I suppose that make sense. Thanks for helping out